# Wireshark filter for all connections

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

So I have two pcaps and I need to get the length of each connection in them and graph them against the connection start times (so y axis is duration and x axis is time). I also need to find connections that did not end with an ACK after a FIN-ACK. I am new to working with pcaps so I am unsure how to do this. I assume wireshark would be easiest but if tcpdump or some other utility would be better that is fine as well. Can anyone help me with a filter?

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is a question&answer site for questions about programming. Your question is off-topic.I recommend to ask at the Wireshark User maling list (https://www.wireshark.org/lists/).

Comment: I've seen a decent number of wireshark questions here which is why I figured I would ask here as well